# Retrofit Task (Execute) Called from another function doesn't wait until Task finish

Tags: java, android, asynchronous

From my Login Activity (First Activity Opened) I always do a check if the token is still active on my server which is done through Async Task that does API call to server.

here's the code from LoginActivity :

```
 private void checkIfAuthenticated(){
    SharedPreferences reader_auth = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.auth_preferences), MODE_PRIVATE);

    String auth_key = reader_auth.getString(getString(R.string.auth_access_key),null);
    String mobile_token = reader_auth.getString(getString(R.string.auth_mobile_token),null);

    if (auth_key != null) {
        //THIS PART RUNS THE TOKEN CHECK TO SERVER
        authGlobal = new AuthenticationGlobal(this);
        // I WANT THIS FUNCTION TO FINISH FIRST BEFORE IT GOES TO THE NEXT PART OF THE CODE
        authGlobal.runAuthenticationCheck(auth_key,mobile_token);


        String Auth_Key = reader_auth.getString(getString(R.string.auth_access_key),null);

        Log.d("Auth Key Check 0",Auth_Key);
        if (Auth_Key != null) {
            Log.d("Auth Key Check 1",Auth_Key);
            MoveToDashboardActivity();
        }

    }
}
```

The runAuthenticationCheck(String,String) Code is located on another class (Because it was meant to be a global function which can be called from any function on any activity)

runAuthenticationCheck is located in AuthenticationGlobal Class, here's the code :

```
public void runAuthenticationCheck (String mobile_token, String Access_token) {
    checkAuthTask = new checkAuthenticationTask(mobile_token, Access_token);
    checkAuthTask.execute((Void) null);
}

public class checkAuthenticationTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {


    private GetDataService service;
    private String mobile_token;
    private String access_token;
    checkAuthenticationTask( String Access_token,String Mobile_token) {
        /*Create handle for the RetrofitInstance interface*/
        mobile_token = Mobile_token;
        access_token = Access_token;

        service = RetrofitClientInstance.getRetrofitInstance().create(GetDataService.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO: attempt authentication against a network service.
        try {
            Call<CheckAuthenticationResponse> call = service.checkAuthentication(access_token,mobile_token);

            Response<CheckAuthenticationResponse> CheckAuthenticationResponse = call.execute();

            if (CheckAuthenticationResponse.code() == 200){


            } else{
                //clear shared preferences
                clearAuthentication();
                Log.e("AuthKey Global","Expired0");
            }

        } catch (IOException ea) {
            clearAuthentication();
            Log.e("AuthKey Global","Expired1");
            Log.e("AuthenticationResponseError Global","Network Went Wrong");
            ea.printStackTrace();
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
        //mAuthTask = null;
        //showProgress(false);
        if (success) {
            Log.e("AuthKey Global","Done");
        } else {
           // mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_incorrect_password));

            clearAuthentication();
            Log.e("AuthKey Global","Expired2");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        //mAuthTask = null;
        //showProgress(false);
    }
```

There are 2 Class / Activity : "LoginActivity" and "AuthenticationGlobal".

There are 3 Function :

1. checkIfAuthenticated => located in LoginActivity, Which in turn actually call another function from another class (Function number 2 : "runAuthenticationCheck")
2. runAuthenticationCheck => located in AuthenticationGlobal. which in calls a AsyncTask via .execute(...) command.
3. checkAuthenticationTask => located in AuthenticationGlobal. Which actually does the API Call to server.

From "LoginActivity" I run a function "checkIfAuthenticated" => which calls function "runAuthenticationCheck" located at "AuthenticationGlobal" => which runs a Task "checkAuthenticationTask" which does API Call to server and does stuff.

The problem is, when I called the first Function, the code doesn't wait until the function "checkIfAuthenticated" / "checkAuthenticationTask" is done. Is there a way for me to make the app wait until the task / function finish first??

Thank you

**UPDATE :**
I ONLY NEED TO ADD .get() at the end of .execute() and wrap it inside try catch.

```
public void runAuthenticationCheck (String mobile_token, String Access_token) {
        checkAuthTask = new checkAuthenticationTask(mobile_token, Access_token);
        try {
            checkAuthTask.execute((Void) null).get();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well. I just need to add a .get() on the execute() and wrap it inside a try catch.

A dumb mistake.

here's the updated code :

```
public void runAuthenticationCheck (String mobile_token, String Access_token) {
        checkAuthTask = new checkAuthenticationTask(mobile_token, Access_token);
        try {
            checkAuthTask.execute((Void) null).get();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```